# Change textarea height in facebook connect feed post dialog on ios

Tags: objective-c, ios, facebook

i have this simple code (after authorization), which show post dialog to facebook news feed.

```
NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               message, @"message",
                               nil];
[facebook dialog:@"feed"
       andParams:params 
     andDelegate:self];
```

Dialog opens without problem, but height of textarea is very small, for about 2 lines, but below is lot of space and i have predefined long text to post.

Is there a way to change height of textarea?

Thanks Lukas

--- EDIT ---

I found "dirty" way of doing this by changing FBDialog.m

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
  [_spinner stopAnimating];
  _spinner.hidden = YES;

  [_webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementsByName('feedform_user_message')[0].rows = 8;"];

  self.title = [_webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.title"];
  [self updateWebOrientation];
}
```

but its not best solution... any better ideas?

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing in the FB SDK that will handle this "cleanly".  If you want to tweak things, you'll have to take a "dirty" approach as you suggest.  But every time you refresh the FBConnect code, you'll have to remember to add your tweaks again.  It's probably best just to let them display the dialog their way.  I've decided to stop trying to fight their SDK.